# How to change WordPress Gallery thumbnail into Sliding?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my website user can upload photos to a page, But the thumbnails keep going down if it has lot of photos.

The layout of thumbnails that keeps going down and eat lot of spaces:

[image: The layout of thumbnails that keeps going down and eat lot of spaces]

Is there a way to change the thumbnails into sliding?

Here's the code

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'horizon_submission_listing_metabox_allowed', true, 'gallery', get_the_author_meta('ID') ) ): ?>
    <?php $gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), HORIZON_LISTING_PREFIX . 'gallery', true ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $gallery ) && is_array( $gallery ) ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-detail-section" id="listing-detail-section-gallery">
            <h2 class="page-header"><?php echo $section_title; ?></h2>

            <div class="listing-detail-gallery-wrapper" >
                <div class="listing-detail-gallery" >
                    <?php $index = 0; ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $gallery as $id => $src ) : ?>
                        <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'large' ); ?>
                        <?php $src = $img[0]; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>" rel="listing-gallery" data-item-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $index++ ); ?>">
                            <span class="item-image" data-background-image="<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>"></span><!-- /.item-image -->
                        </a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>


                <!-- /.listing-detail-gallery -->

                <div class="listing-detail-gallery-preview" data-count="<?php echo count( $gallery ) ?>">
                    <div class="listing-detail-gallery-preview-inner">
                        <?php $index = 0; ?>
                        <?php foreach ( $gallery as $id => $src ) : ?>
                            <div data-item-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $index++ ); ?>">
                                <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                                <?php $img_src = $img[0]; ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div><!-- /.listing-detail-gallery-preview-inner -->
                </div><!-- /.listing-detail-gallery-preview -->
            </div><!-- /.listing-detail-gallery-wrapper -->
        </div><!-- /.listing-detail-section -->
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Instead of making changes in code, use any image slider plugin, that will be easy for you. Because there is loads of dependency on this code, so if you make changes in this code you need to make changes in several places.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code this yourself, then you would need to apply some changes in CSS and add javascript code to create navigation for slider. 
The simplest way of doing that would be using for example jQuery, hiding all images and showing only one that is being currently viewed.
You could all navigation buttons to coordinate showing/hiding the photos.

More advanced solution which provides additional features would be to use a slider plugin, like this for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-responsive-image-slider/